# Should we avoid plural names for variables?

Tags: c++, stl, naming-conventions

Sometimes it is tempting to name a variable as plural when its a collection of objects like an array or list. Is this okay or should we always stick to singular names for variables? As one example a collection of cars could be called 'cars' or 'car'

Consider another example:

```
    vector< string > students; // it is named as students rather singular student

    students.push_back("Mark");
    students.push_back("Steve");

     // lets say we are using index to retrieve it, it does look 
     // a little clumsy

    string current_student = students[0];
```

Alternatively we can define the container object as singular like below but does it look like to represent a single object now instead of collection of students? It does make using index look better though.

```
    vector< string > student;
```

Another option that I personally like is something like this:

```
   vector< string > student_list;
```

I append '_list' (or could be camel notation) to the collection variable name (irrespective if its vector or list or map). This way name of the object is singular yet it identifies itself as collection of objects.

Which is a better way or convention and more readable of the above? Should plural names be absolutely avoided?

Also think of another simpler example as well, say we are conducting an experiment where we record temperatures of a day 100 times at different intervals so we :

```
     float temperatures[100]; // or temperature[100]? or temperature_list[100]?
```

or perhaps even different like:

```
    float temperature_data[100]?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plurals are fine -- in fact, i'd go as far as to say *expected* - when the name refers to a collection of items (ie: a set, list, vector, array, etc).  Names like `temperature_data` can be ambiguous as to whether they refer to a single item or a bunch of them.  `temperatures`, on the other hand, clearly refers to more than one.

Comment: Stupid nitpick: `temperature_data` is the plural of `temperature_datum` :P

Comment: I'd agree with you if anyone actually used the word "datum" anymore.  :)  These days, "data" is a mass noun, and is considered singular at least as often as it is plural.

Comment: Would this go for a namespace name as well? So, a namespace containing several policy classes should be named `policies` rather than `policy`?

Comment: Namespace names, i'd think, would work either way, as long as you keep it consistent.

Answer (score 8):

Err, why would it not be okay? In the end, it doesn't really matter which convention you'll come up with, what matters is that it's used consistently, and doesn't impact readability negatively.

Comment: However, having `student` *and* `students` in the same scope would pose readability issues :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I dunno.  It'd definitely be bad to have `students = student;`.  But if `student` is always *a* student, then it could easily be an appropriate name for the variable representing the "current" student as you're looping through `students`.

Answer (score 5):

If the thing/object is a plural, then you should name it with a plural name.

I don't think the `students[0]` example is confusing at all. I read it as "students-sub-zero" which basically means get me whatever is in students index zero. If I've named things properly it should be obvious that the thing is a student (singular).

Comment: Currently, I have the arrays `particles`, `ions` but `surfactant` in a program, since `surfactants` would refer to multiple types of surfactant instead of multiple surfactant molecules of the same type. I'm a little uncomfortable with that...

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem having plurals - as long as you avoid having the singular and plural in the same scope. Just make variables descriptive.